# Is there an accepted pattern to preserve variables' values during a function call which modifies those variables?

Tags: c#

Within a class I have a property used by a method which I want to remain in the same state after a call to a second method (which might alter that state).

Example: for a property `Value` I could do something like this:

```
void MethodOne()
{ 
...
    var tempValue = this.Value;
    MethodTwo();                   // might modify this.Value
    this.Value = tempValue;
...
}
```

For a single property this isn't a big deal. If I have multiple properties it gets uglier.

I'm looking for a C# solution but would be interested to know if this kind of construct appears in any common language. The sort of syntax I'm after might look something like this:

```
void MethodOne()
{ 
...
    preserving(this.Value)
    {
        MethodTwo();               // might modify this.Value
    }
...
}
```

where the `preserving` keyword could potentially accept multiple properties/fields.

In my specific case it's a recursive method, so the code looks more like:

```
void MethodOne(object[] args)
{ 
...
    // Do something which might modify this.Value

    preserving(this.Value)
    {
        MethodOne(args);
    }
...
}
```

**Is there an accepted pattern / best practice to achieve this?**

**EDIT**

The specific case for which I'm asking is something like this:

For the purposes of sorting lists I have a custom comparison class which implements IComparer. Its `Compare` method acts on objects which appear in collections (which may therefore be sorted). These collections might be nested, so sorting such a collection might result in the sort function, and therefore Compare(), being called recursively.

The actual comparison function is partially dynamic, which means that it could be set at runtime to something invalid (e.g. non-transitive or non-deterministic). I can't prevent this, so I want to set a limit on the number of comparisons (let's say n-squared, where n is the length of the list being sorted) to protect against cases where an invalid comparison function might result in the sorting algorithm going into an infinite loop.

The `Compare` method might be called from (e.g.) various LINQ methods such as `OrderBy`, possibly resulting in lazily evaluated sorts and possibly from code over which I have no control. However, I need to count the number of comparisons in each sort without any 'subsorts' of nested objects corrupting the count (but also counting comparisons in those subsorts).

My code looks something like this:

```
public int Compare(T x, T y)
{
    // this.MaxComparisons is set from outside this code, since this method does not know the length of the list it is sorting.
    
    if (++this.ComparisonCount > this.MaxComparisons)
    {
        // Error: too many comparisons
    }

    if (predicate)
    {
        // Preserve...
        tempComparisonCount = this.ComparisonCount;
        tempMaxComparisons = this.MaxComparisons;
        
        // ...reset...
        this.ComparisonCount = 0;
        this.MaxComparisons = ... ;   // set as required
        
        var result = this.customComparer.Compare(x.Child, y.Child);    // might involve further calls to the above method, which should be counted separately
        
        // ...and restore
        this.ComparisonCount = tempComparisonCount;
        this.MaxComparisons = tempMaxComparisons;

        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return otherComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

I hope this makes it clearer why I have asked the question.

Comment: IMO, if you need to do this, then you've already done something wrong.

Comment: Pretty much what CodingGorilla has stated. MethodTwo should be refactored to do less things, and slowly reconstruct your code from there. Do you really need your methods to work on fields/properties? Can't you modify your methods to use parameters and return values?

Comment: Thank you; these are both fair comments. I can't currently see how to refactor cleanly, so I've posted some more details which will hopefully make it clearer why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: As expected, your specific situation makes it clear that the value you're using should be a parameter to the recursive method, rather than an instance field.  That removes all of your problems.

Comment: @Servy, this is an implementation of the Compare method on the IComparer interface; I can't just add a parameter, much as I'd like to. The method can be called by e.g. LINQ's `OrderBy` method which accepts a custom comparer. I need to manage those sorts, wherever they're called from. How can I implement your suggestion of adding a parameter here?

Comment: @Neil Create a second method with an additional parameter that does the actual implementation, and have the interface method call that method with a default value (in this case, zero) for the additional parameter.  You see this all over the place whenever you have recursive methods.

Comment: @Servy et al - thanks for your comments. In the cold light of morning it dawns on me that the problem, even with this 'extra parameter' idea, is that the 'Compare' interface method doesn't know which sort or subsort it's being called from. If I use a new instance of the comparer for each sort / subsort then each instance can count its own comparisons, with minimal performance/memory cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void Preserving<T>(ref T value, Action act)
{
    T old = value;
    act();
    value = old;
}
```

then you can do:

```
Preserving(ref this.Value, MethodTwo);
```

If you have multiple variables you want to save and restore, you should probably create a `Context` class containing the state you want to save and then push/pop them from a stack.

Comment: Thanks @Lee. I'd be interested to know whether any languages come with this construct built in. Given the recursive nature of the actual case in question, your stack suggestion is perhaps the cleanest way.

Comment: While the comments on the question above were useful (if somewhat patronising in places), your response does actually answer what I asked, so (unless anyone comes up with examples of languages where this syntax is built in) I'm going to mark yours as the best answer. Thanks.